# tmux - How to change text color of current pane to yellow if pane is in copy-mode

Tags: colors, tmux

In tmux 3.3a on Ubuntu 23.10 I would like to change text color yellow if current pane is in copy-mode (pressing prefix_key + PageUp) and when exiting copy-mode to get text back to grey.

I tried:

```
set-hook -g pane-mode-changed 'if -F "#{m/r:(copy|view)-mode,#{pane_mode}}" "set window-active-style fg=yellow" "set -u window-active-style fg=grey"'
```

I have tested. Start tmux and type some command e.g. dir and press `prefix_key + PageUp` and color of text correctly changes to yellow. If I press `CTRL+C` it changes back to grey. Just like I want.

Now create second pane: `prefix_key + "` also execute some command e.g. dir and press `prefix_key + PageUp` and color changes to yellow as expected. Now move to another pane (without exiting copy-mode in current pane) with `prefix_key + ArrowUp` and first pane gets yellow text color, despite not being in copy-mode. In this case I want text to stay grey, because current pane is in 'normal' mode.

Comment: `set-hook -g window-pane-changed 'if -F …`?

Comment: I tested your suggestion and exactly the same problem. In first pane `prefix_key + PageUp` and text correctly changes from grey to yellow. But when I move to previous pane (that is not in copy-mode) with `prefix_key + ArrowUp` that previous pane also text changes to yellow. I only want to have yellow text for panes that are in copy-mode.

Comment: Did you actually test it? Adding to `.tmux.conf` does not affect the already running tmux server (see the beginning of [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/757783/108618)). Run `tmux set-hook -g window-pane-changed 'if -F …` in a shell inside tmux.

Comment: Just to make sure now I have changed the setting in .tmux.conf file and rebooted Ubuntu. Starting shell and tmux. Typed in "dir" command and then opened another pane `prefix_key+"`, typed in "dir" command. Now pressed `prefix_key+PageUp`  to enter into copy-mode and text does NOT changes to yellow, it stays in grey. Jump to first pane `prefix_key+ArrowUp` and text is grey as expected. Jump back to second pane `prefix_key+ArrowDown`  and text gets yellow as expected, because pane it is still in copy-mode. Exit copy-mode with `Ctrl+C` and text is still in yellow, a would like to have it in grey.

Comment: Sigh… It seems you now have the new hook for `window-pane-changed`, but not the old hook for `pane-mode-changed`. Did you remove the old hook that did *its* job right?

Comment: Now I understand. I should have both hooks. I added both of them (yours and mine) to the config file and now it looks it works like I imagined. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moving to another pane does not trigger `pane-mode-changed`, it triggers `window-pane-changed`. The simplest improvement is to define two hooks:

```
set-hook -g pane-mode-changed   '…'   # you already have this
set-hook -g window-pane-changed '…'   # same action, different trigger
```

Comment: For test in first line I have set "yellow" color and in second "red" to understand when actually first hook is triggered and when second one. After that of course I have set both to the "yellow" again. Thanks for help. By the way, I now see this is tmux v3 solution. I have some older machines also with tmux v2.7 (Red Hat 8) and this hooks do not work. Probably new feature of tmux v3.